# Subquery - W3Resources

Tags: mysql, database, join, where-clause, sql-in

I was wondering if my code works or not? 
Question #3 on [this w3school exercise](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/subquery-exercises/find-the-names-of-the-employees-who-have-a-manager-who-works-for-a-department-based-in-united-states.php) :

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM employees
WHERE 
    manager_id IS NOT NULL
    AND manager_id IN (
        SELECT manager_id
        FROM departments
        WHERE location_id IN (
            SELECT location_id 
            FROM locations
            WHERE country_id='US' 
        )
    )
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code should work.

Please note that the part of the SQL that checks if manager_id is not null is superfluous and can be removed (the IN clause already ensures that manager_id is set).

It is possible to optimize the query using a set of JOINs, like :

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.last_name
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.manager_id = e.manager_id
INNER JOIN locations l ON l.department_id = d.department_id AND l.country_id='US'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response GMB